# Compare filenames with foldernames and move matching filenames elsewhere

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need to compare filenames (minus extension) in folder A with foldernames in folder B.

If the filename minus extension has a matching foldername in folderB then move it to FolderC.

Example:

I have 3 directories: A, B and C

In folder A there are *.txt files.
In folder B are several folders

if a foldername (in folderB) has the same rootname as a filename in folderA then move the folderA file to folder C.

Comment: Please supply more information about the task.  Example of files and folders will help.

Comment: Do you have other folders in folderB called 1, 2  and 3?  The task is not clear.  I suspect you are using a non-latin character set too and maybe Unicode.  That can affect the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it from the cmd prompt.  Double all `%` to `%%` if it is inside a batch file.

```
for /d %a in ("folderb\*") do if exist "foldera\%~nxa.txt" move "foldera\%~nxa.txt" "folderc"
```

**Answer 2**

Your task (in this answers comments) can be turned around, to delete the `.apk files` that `do not` have a matching folder in `_Dicts` folder.

If that is what you need to do then test this:

```
@echo off
for %%a in ("_INPUT_APK\*.apk") do if not exist "_Dicts\%%~na\" del "%%a"
```